# Is there an issue with SE showing embedded pictures?

Tags: support, bug, images

I've noticed today that several images are *not* being embedded in the post as they should, instead they're showing up only as links. For example [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/201092).

I tried to edit it to get it to embed the image, as that's much easier to see, but even copying the imjur link and readding it wouldn't make it show up properly. Is this a new bug in SE? Is it purely a Firefox issue? Is it something else?

I'm running FF 79.0 64-bit on Win10, and this just seems to have started today. I've not had any Windows or FF updates in the last week or so.

Comment: Are you still seeing this? I couldn't reproduce it with Chrome or FireFox.

Comment: I've been getting the Cloudflare captcha at nearly all the sites I've visited in the last 24 hours or so, this isn't SE specific. Some research (and several rants later) it seems that they and/or Google or someone has made some changes that's causing this. I've not run into the image problem here at SE again, but I do think I've hit the captcha once or twice here since then.

Comment: This morning, I've been to several questions and the embedded images are all showing up just fine, @NiallC. Maybe it was just Cloudflare having a bad weekend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it may be related to Couldflare nonsense. I clicked on a link and got this message:

[image]

I clicked the checkbox, then clicked on random images (fortunately it seems that I don't have to click on the 'airplane' or 'car' pictures as requested, just any clicks will do), then it let me see the image on imgur. When I returned to DIY, it showed the image.

I'm not sure what's causing this, but I've seen people complaining about this captcha page showing up on a variety of sites. Yet one more way to monetize the "free" internet. :/

Comment: There are many sites that will give this captcha if you try to connect through a VPN or Tor.  In most cases you get straight in if you change to another browser that goes in clear.